I need to display an image in my flutter app from payload cms
I'm creating app using flutter that is supposed to retrieve rich text content from payload CMS in form of json, convert it to html, and display it on the app.
So far the text is being displayed, but when I add the image the image is not being displayed. The image url is correct, even when I run it directly on the browser it brings the image, but on the app it does not display. What am I missing?
Here is the code:
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_html/flutter_html.dart';

class LexicalRichTextConverter extends StatelessWidget {
  final Map<String, dynamic> lexicalContent;

  const LexicalRichTextConverter({Key? key, required this.lexicalContent})
      : super(key: key);

  String convertToHtml() {
    try {
      // Directly use the passed root instead of accessing content
      return _parseNode(lexicalContent['root']);
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error converting Lexical content: $e');
      return '';
    }
  }

  String _parseNode(Map<String, dynamic> node) {
    switch (node['type']) {
      case 'root':
        return _parseRootChildren(node['children'] ?? []);
      case 'paragraph':
        return _parseParagraph(node);
      case 'upload': // Add explicit handling for upload/image type
        return _parseImage(node);
      case 'heading':
        return _parseHeading(node);
      case 'list':
        return _parseList(node);
      case 'listitem':
        return _parseListItem(node);
      case 'quote':
        return _parseQuote(node);
      case 'code':
        return _parseCodeBlock(node);
      case 'image':
        return _parseImage(node);
      case 'link':
        return _parseLink(node);
      default:
        print('Unhandled node type: ${node['type']}');
        return _parseTextNode(node);
    }
  }

  String _parseRootChildren(List<dynamic> children) {
    return children.map((child) => _parseNode(child)).join('');
  }

  String _parseParagraph(Map<String, dynamic> node) {
    final children = node['children'] ?? [];
    final content = children.map((child) => _parseTextNode(child)).join('');
    return '<p>$content</p>';
  }

  String _parseHeading(Map<String, dynamic> node) {
    final level = node['tag'] ?? 1;
    final children = node['children'] ?? [];
    final content = children.map((child) => _parseTextNode(child)).join('');
    return '<h$level>$content</h$level>';
  }

  String _parseList(Map<String, dynamic> node) {
    final tag = node['listType'] == 'ordered' ? 'ol' : 'ul';
    final children = node['children'] ?? [];
    final content = children.map((child) => _parseNode(child)).join('');
    return '<$tag>$content</$tag>';
  }

  String _parseListItem(Map<String, dynamic> node) {
    final children = node['children'] ?? [];
    final content = children.map((child) => _parseTextNode(child)).join('');
    return '<li>$content</li>';
  }

  String _parseQuote(Map<String, dynamic> node) {
    final children = node['children'] ?? [];
    final content = children.map((child) => _parseTextNode(child)).join('');
    return '<blockquote>$content</blockquote>';
  }

  String _parseCodeBlock(Map<String, dynamic> node) {
    final content = node['text'] ?? '';
    return '<pre><code>$content</code></pre>';
  }

  String _parseImage(Map<String, dynamic> node) {
    final baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000';

    try {
      if (node['type'] == 'upload' && node['relationTo'] == 'media') {
        final value = node['value'] ?? {};
        final rawUrl = value['url'] ?? '';
        final fullImageUrl =
            rawUrl.startsWith('/') ? '$baseUrl$rawUrl' : rawUrl;
        final alt = value['alt'] ?? value['filename'] ?? '';

        // Verbose logging
        print('Image URL Details:');
        print('Raw URL: $rawUrl');
        print('Full URL: $fullImageUrl');
        print('Alt Text: $alt');

        return '''
        <img 
          src="$fullImageUrl" 
          alt="$alt" 
          style="max-width:100%; height:auto; display:block;" 
        />
      ''';
      }

      print('Unhandled image node type: ${node['type']}');
      return '';
    } catch (e) {
      print('Image parsing critical error: $e');
      return '';
    }
  }

  String _parseLink(Map<String, dynamic> node) {
    final href = node['href'] ?? '';
    final children = node['children'] ?? [];
    final content = children.map((child) => _parseTextNode(child)).join('');
    return '<a href="$href">$content</a>';
  }

  String _parseTextNode(Map<String, dynamic> node) {
    String text = node['text'] ?? '';

    // Apply text formatting
    if (node['format'] != null) {
      final format = node['format'];
      if (format & 1 != 0) text = '<strong>$text</strong>'; // Bold
      if (format & 2 != 0) text = '<em>$text</em>'; // Italic
      if (format & 4 != 0) text = '<u>$text</u>'; // Underline
      if (format & 8 != 0) text = '<s>$text</s>'; // Strikethrough
    }

    // Apply text style (custom styles)
    if (node['style'] != null) {
      final style = node['style'];
      switch (style) {
        case 'code':
          text = '<code>$text</code>';
          break;
        // Add more custom styles as needed
      }
    }

    return text;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final htmlContent = convertToHtml();
    return Html(
      data: htmlContent,
      style: {
        'body': Style(
          margin: Margins.zero,
        ),
        'img': Style(
          width: Width.auto(),
          height: Height.auto(),
          display: Display.block,
        ),
      },
      
      onCssParseError: (exception, stackTrace) {
        print('Image load error: $exception');

      },
    );
  }
}

// Usage Example
class LexicalContentRenderer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Map<String, dynamic> lexicalContent;

  const LexicalContentRenderer({Key? key, required this.lexicalContent})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LexicalRichTextConverter(lexicalContent: lexicalContent);
  }
}

and here is the debug console results

Received content: {root: {type: root, format: , indent: 0, version: 1, children: [{type: paragraph, format: , indent: 0, version: 1, children: [{mode: normal, text: Noun, type: text, style: , detail: 0, format: 1, version: 1}, {mode: normal, text:  is a part of speech, type: text, style: , detail: 0, format: 0, version: 1}], direction: ltr, textStyle: , textFormat: 1}, {id: 67474007cdcf8a99d68f160e, type: upload, value: {id: 1, alt: google, prefix: media, updatedAt: 2024-11-27T15:51:31.463Z, createdAt: 2024-11-27T15:51:31.463Z, url: /api/media/file/google.png, thumbnailURL: null, filename: google.png, mimeType: image/png, filesize: 18527, width: 512, height: 512, focalX: 50, focalY: 50}, fields: null, format: , version: 3, relationTo: media}, {type: paragraph, format: , indent: 0, version: 1, children: [], direction: null, textStyle: , textFormat: 0}, {type: paragraph, format: , indent: 0, version: 1, children: [], direction: ltr, textStyle: , textFormat: 0}], direction: ltr}}
flutter: Image URL Details:
flutter: Raw URL: /api/media/file/google.png
flutter: Full URL: http://localhost:3000/api/media/file/google.png
flutter: Alt Text: google

